# If $f, g \in L^{p}(\mu)$ then $f\vee g$ and $f\wedge g \in L^{p}(\mu)$

Tags: measure-theory

How can I prove If $f, g \in L^{p}(\mu)$ then  $f\vee g$ and $f\wedge g \in L^{p}(\mu)$
I think that I can use $f\vee g=\frac{1}{2}(f+g+|f-g|)$ and $f\wedge g=\frac{1}{2}(f+g-|f-g|)$ but I don't know how.

Comment: Hint: $L^p$ is a vector space. So it's closed under addition and scalar multiplication. To verify that $|f-g|$ is in the $L^p$ space, you can use Minkowsi's inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint.

Comment: You could also just say: if $E := \{ x \mid f(x) \ge g(x) \}$ then $\int |f \vee g|^p\,d\mu = \int_E |f|^p\,d\mu + \int_{E^c} |g|^p\,d\mu \le \lVert f \rVert_p^p + \lVert g \rVert_p^p < \infty$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thank you for that

Comment: $\max(|f|,|g|) \le |f|+|g|$.